# Recursive Merge Sort with non-recursive merge

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

I am trying to code a recursive merge sort algorithm, however my merging algorithm is not recursive.

I have been told to do it using the following arguments in the functions below.

```
def merge(left_buffer, right_buffer, data):
    
    "Merges two sets of data together by comparison"
    print("MERGING",left_buffer,"and",right_buffer)
    #Dual iteration
    m = 1
    n = 1
    k = 0
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if len(left_buffer) == 0:
            data[i] = right_buffer[k]
            k+=1
        elif len(right_buffer) == 0:
            data[i] = left_buffer[j]
            j += 1
        elif left_buffer[0] < right_buffer[0]:
            data[i] = left_buffer[0]
            left_buffer = left_buffer[1:]
            
        else:
            data[i] = right_buffer[0]
            right_buffer = right_buffer[1:]
    print('Result of the merge:',data)
```

This is my function to merge two data sets together into another data set.

And then my recursive merge sort algorithm:

```
def merge_sort(data):
    "Merge sort recursion"
    if len(data) == 1:
        return [data[0]]
    else:
        half_length = len(data)//2
        left_half = data[0:half_length]
        right_half = data[half_length:]
        
        #Only sorting the left side
        left = merge_sort(left_half)
        right = merge_sort(right_half)
        
        return merge(left,right,data)
```

The main problem I receive is that upon the final merge of the two lists I get that I am merging `None` types.

I am not sure how to solve this.

Maybe my merging algorithm is incorrect, however my tutor said it was fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `merge` method doesn't return anything, so when your `merge_sort` method returns, it also returns `None`.

These `None` values get passed into `left` and `right`, which you then pass into your `merge` method.

Perhaps you want your `merge_sort` method to do the merge and then return the merged data?  I.e.:

```
    merge(left,right,data)
    return data
```

Alternatively, you could modify `merge` so that it returned the merged data, by adding the line `return data` to the end of it.